# Reverse for ''home'' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: python, django

I receive "Reverse for ''home'' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found" error in django. can anybody help me to solve this.

my base.html is

```
   <html>
<head>
  <title>Steel Rumors</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Steel Rumors</h1>

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}

<footer>
  <p>
    <a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a>
 </p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

my urls.py is

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from links.views import LinkListView

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', LinkListView.as_view(), name='home'),

    url(r"^login/$", "django.contrib.auth.views.login",
        {"template_name": "login.html"}, name="login"),
    url(r"^logout/$", "django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login",
        name="logout"),
)
```

view.py is

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Link, Vote

class LinkListView(ListView):
    model = Link
    queryset = Link.with_votes.all()
    paginate_by = 3
```

django version 1.4
Thanks in advance

Comment: which version of django you are using ?

Comment: Set `DEBUG=True` it will give you more detailed info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you to call url into your base.html like

```
<footer>
  <p>
    <a href="{% url home %}">Home</a>
 </p>
</footer>
```

write url name  without quotes .

Comment: without quotes may be wrong if django version>=1.5,must write {% url 'home' %}

Answer (score 0):

I met the same question before,the argument is page,try `{% url 'home' 1 %}`
I usually do it like this(Django 1.6),I wonder if a better way will be found to solve this!
Other answers are welcome!

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def reaction_list_home(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('list', args=(1,)))
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from reactions import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.reaction_list_home, name='list-home'),
    url(r'^pages/(?P<page>\d+)/$', views.ReactionList.as_view(),name='list'),
)
```